# JComboBox Issue

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an assignment in my CS12 class, which to create a program where can be combined `JRadioButon/JCheckBox/JComboBox` all together.

As of now I am very confused with `JComboBox`, I don't understand what exactly am i missing in an `ActionListener` part.

First I can't choose any option from the third column( Colour & Interior ), it is simply doesn't shows up on the label created in the same column.

Second, I can't see the values of the `JCheckBoxes` created in the second column, before I chose the province from the fourth column.

Will accept any advise, thank you. 
// please excuse for my english, I am not a native speaker.

import javax.swing.*;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VolvoStore extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    private JButton btnCheckout;
    private JButton btnClear;
    private JButton btnExit;
    private JButton btnAbout;

    private JLabel txt1 = new JLabel();// total
    private JLabel txt2 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt3 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt4 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt5 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt6 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt7 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel txt8 = new JLabel();

    Double m;
    Double k;

    JCheckBox chk = new JCheckBox("Climate Package [Add $1,350.00]");
    JCheckBox chk1 = new JCheckBox("Technology Package [Add $1,500.00]");
    JCheckBox chk2 = new JCheckBox("Inscription Package [Add $2,600.00]");
    JCheckBox chk3 = new JCheckBox(
            "19\" BOR Diamond Cut Alloy Wheels [Add $1,250.00]");
    JCheckBox chk4 = new JCheckBox(
            "Blind Spot Information System [Add $800.00]");
    JCheckBox chk5 = new JCheckBox(
            "Active Dual Xenon Headlights with Washers [Add $1,000.00]");
    JCheckBox chk6 = new JCheckBox("Front and Rear Park Assist [Add $600.00]");
    JCheckBox chk7 = new JCheckBox(
            "Apple CarPlay System + Bose Sound System [Add $2400.00]");

    private JRadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label11 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label12 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label13 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label14 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label15 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label16 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label17 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label18 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label19 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label20 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label21 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label111 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label112 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label113 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label114 = new JLabel();

    private JLabel tx = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx2 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx3 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx4 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx4a = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx5 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx6 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx7 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx71 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx72 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel tx73 = new JLabel();

    double total;
    double total1;

    JComboBox<String> cboAColor;
    JComboBox<String> cboBColor;
    JComboBox<String> cboCColor;
    JComboBox<String> cboProvinces;

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int d1 = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private JTextField text1 = new JTextField("", 16);// total bill

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VolvoStore();
    }

    public VolvoStore() {

        // OK Button
        btnCheckout = new JButton("Checkout");
        btnCheckout.setToolTipText("Checkout");
        btnCheckout.setBounds(1315, 150, 120, 40);
        btnCheckout.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        btnCheckout.setBorderPainted(false);
        panel.add(btnCheckout);

        // Clear
        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.setToolTipText("Clear");
        btnClear.setBounds(1315, 200, 120, 40);
        btnClear.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        btnClear.setBorderPainted(false);
        panel.add(btnClear);
        // EXIT
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.setToolTipText("Exit");
        btnExit.setBounds(1315, 250, 120, 40);
        btnExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        btnExit.setBorderPainted(false);
        panel.add(btnExit);

        // ABOUT
        btnAbout = new JButton("About");
        btnAbout.setToolTipText("About");
        btnAbout.setBounds(1315, 300, 120, 40);
        btnAbout.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        btnAbout.setBorderPainted(false);
        panel.add(btnAbout);
//user input
        panel.add(text1);
        text1.setBounds(1275, 775, 200, 35);
        text1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//total MSRP 
        txt1.setText("0.0");
        txt1.setBounds(1300, 575, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt1);
        txt1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
// 1st column
        txt2.setText("0.0");
        txt2.setBounds(155, 875, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt2);
        txt2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//Second Column
        txt3.setText("0.0");
        txt3.setBounds(575, 875, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt3);
        txt3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
// total Selling Price
        txt4.setText("0.0");
        txt4.setBounds(1300, 875, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt4);
        txt4.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//Freight & Dealer Prep
        txt5.setText("10.0");
        txt5.setBounds(1300, 675, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt5);
        txt5.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//third column
        txt6.setText("0.0");
        txt6.setBounds(965, 875, 140, 40);
        panel.add(txt6);
        txt6.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        //check buttons in a second column + radio button and images from the first column 
        panel.add(chk);
        panel.add(chk1);
        panel.add(chk2);
        panel.add(chk3);
        panel.add(chk4);
        panel.add(chk5);
        panel.add(chk6);
        panel.add(chk7);

        chk.setBounds(450, 50, 540, 40);
        chk1.setBounds(450, 150, 540, 40);
        chk2.setBounds(450, 250, 540, 40);
        chk3.setBounds(450, 350, 540, 40);
        chk4.setBounds(450, 450, 540, 40);
        chk5.setBounds(450, 550, 540, 40);
        chk6.setBounds(450, 650, 540, 40);
        chk7.setBounds(450, 750, 540, 40);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        btnCheckout.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        btnAbout.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        chk.addItemListener(this);
        chk1.addItemListener(this);
        chk2.addItemListener(this);
        chk3.addItemListener(this);
        chk4.addItemListener(this);
        chk5.addItemListener(this);
        chk6.addItemListener(this);
        chk7.addItemListener(this);
        // images
        ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon("S80.png");
        label1.setIcon(imgThisImg);
        label1.setBounds(25, 450, 550, 590);
        panel.add(label1);
        label1.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg1 = new ImageIcon("XC90.png");
        label2.setIcon(imgThisImg1);
        label2.setBounds(25, -50, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label2);
        label2.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg2 = new ImageIcon("XC70.png");
        label3.setIcon(imgThisImg2);
        label3.setBounds(25, 150, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label3);
        label3.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg3 = new ImageIcon("XC60.png");
        label4.setIcon(imgThisImg3);
        label4.setBounds(25, 350, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label4);
        label4.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg4 = new ImageIcon("Volvo.jpeg");
        label5.setIcon(imgThisImg4);
        label5.setBounds(-10, -170, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label5);
        label5.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg5 = new ImageIcon("012.png");
        label6.setIcon(imgThisImg5);
        label6.setBounds(1275, 290, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label6);
        label6.setOpaque(false);

        ImageIcon imgThisImg6 = new ImageIcon("sun.png");
        label7.setIcon(imgThisImg6);
        label7.setBounds(1275, 220, 680, 390);
        panel.add(label7);
        label7.setOpaque(false);

        // Create radio buttons
        rb1 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC90");
        rb2 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC70");
        rb3 = new JRadioButton("Volvo XC60");
        rb4 = new JRadioButton("Vovlo S80");

        // Create button group for soup options
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rb1);
        group.add(rb2);
        group.add(rb3);
        group.add(rb4);

        // Create soup panel

        rb1.setBounds(0, 200, 120, 40);
        rb2.setBounds(0, 400, 120, 40);
        rb3.setBounds(0, 600, 120, 40);
        rb4.setBounds(0, 800, 120, 40);

        //panel.add(label);
        //label.setBounds(200, -150, 550, 590);

        rb1.addItemListener(this);
        rb2.addItemListener(this);
        rb3.addItemListener(this);
        rb4.addItemListener(this);

        // text at the top and side

        Font a = new Font("Greek", Font.PLAIN, 20);

        tx.setText("Step 1: Model");
        tx.setBounds(125, 0, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx);

        tx2.setText("Step 2: Packages & Options ");
        tx2.setBounds(520, 0, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx2);

        tx3.setText("Step 3: Paint & Interior");
        tx3.setBounds(925, 0, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx3);

        tx4.setText("Step 4: Final Payment");
        tx4.setBounds(1275, 0, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx4);

        tx4a.setText("Total MSRP");
        tx4a.setBounds(1275, 525, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx4a);

        tx5.setText("Freight & Dealer Preparation");
        tx5.setBounds(1275, 625, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx5);

        tx6.setText("Trade-in and Down Payment ");
        tx6.setBounds(1275, 725, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx6);

        tx7.setText("Total Selling Price");
        tx7.setBounds(1275, 825, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx7);

        tx71.setText("Select Upholstery");
        tx71.setBounds(985, 350, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx71);

        tx72.setText("Select Trim");
        tx72.setBounds(1000, 550, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx72);

        tx73.setText("Select Color");
        tx73.setBounds(1000, 150, 300, 40);
        panel.add(tx73);

        tx.setFont(a);
        tx2.setFont(a);
        tx3.setFont(a);
        tx4.setFont(a);

        //
        // Create main panel

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(rb1);
        panel.add(rb2);
        panel.add(rb3);
        panel.add(rb4);

        //Jcombobox at third and fourth columns 

        String[] aa = { "Black Sapphire" ,"Electric Silver", "Passion Red [add $200.00]",
                "Crystal White Pearl [add $200.00]" };
        cboAColor = new JComboBox<String>(aa);
        panel.add(cboAColor);
        cboAColor.setBounds(940, 100, 200, 200);

        String[] bb = { "Black/Black ARTICO Leather, without additional charge",
                "Alpaca Grey/Alpaca Grey ARTICO Leather, without additional charge",
                "Almond Beige/Cashmere Beige ARTICO Leather [add $350.00]" };
        cboBColor = new JComboBox<String>(bb);
        panel.add(cboBColor);
        cboBColor.setBounds(940, 300, 200, 200);

        String[] cc = { "Burl Walnut Wood, without additional charge",  "Dark Ash Wood, without additional charge", "Aluminum[add $200]" };
        cboCColor = new JComboBox<String>(cc);
        panel.add(cboCColor);
        cboCColor.setBounds(940, 500, 200, 200);

        String[] dd = { "Select Province", "Ontario", "Quebeck", "Nova Scotia",
                "New Brunswick", "Manitoba", "British Colombia",
                "Prince Edward Island", "Saskatchewan", "Alberta",
                "Newfoundland and Labrador" };
        cboProvinces = new JComboBox<String>(dd);
        panel.add(cboProvinces);
        cboProvinces.setBounds(1275, 000, 200, 200);

        cboAColor.addItemListener(this);
        cboBColor.addItemListener(this);
        cboCColor.addItemListener(this);
        cboProvinces.addItemListener(this);

        // borders ...
        panel.add(label11);

        label11.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label11.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label11.setBounds(125, 875, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        label11.setOpaque(false);
        // create black border for a Clear Button
        panel.add(label12);
        label12.setOpaque(false);
        label12.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label12.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label12.setBounds(550, 875, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        // create black border for a Clear Button

        panel.add(label13);
        label13.setOpaque(false);
        label13.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label13.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set
                                                                        // color
        label13.setBounds(940, 875, 200, 35);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label14);
        label14.setOpaque(false);
        label14.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label14.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label14.setBounds(1275, 875, 200, 35);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label15);
        label15.setOpaque(false);
        label15.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label15.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label15.setBounds(1275, 775, 200, 35);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label16);
        label16.setOpaque(false);
        label16.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label16.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label16.setBounds(1275, 675, 200, 35);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label17);
        label17.setOpaque(false);
        label17.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label17.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set //
                                                                        // color
        label17.setBounds(1275, 575, 200, 35);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label18);
        label18.setOpaque(false);
        label18.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label18.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));// set
                                                                            // //
        // color
        label18.setBounds(0, -100, 445, 1100);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label19);
        label19.setOpaque(false);
        label19.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label19.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));// set
                                                                            // //
        // color
        label19.setBounds(445, -100, 415, 1100);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label20);
        label20.setOpaque(false);
        label20.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label20.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));// set
                                                                            // //
        // color
        label20.setBounds(860, -100, 360, 1100);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label21);
        label21.setOpaque(false);

        label21.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label21.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));// set
                                                                            // //
        // color
        label21.setBounds(1220, -100, 360, 1100);// bounds and location

        panel.add(label111);

        label111.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label111.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set
                                                                        // //
                                                                        // color
        label111.setBounds(1275, 150, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        label111.setOpaque(false);

        panel.add(label112);

        label112.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label112.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set
                                                                        // //
                                                                        // color
        label112.setBounds(1275, 200, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        label112.setOpaque(false);

        panel.add(label113);

        label113.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label113.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set
                                                                        // //
                                                                        // color
        label113.setBounds(1275, 250, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        label113.setOpaque(false);

        panel.add(label114);

        label114.setBackground(Color.white);// set background color
        label114.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));// set
                                                                        // //
                                                                        // color
        label114.setBounds(1275, 300, 200, 35);// bounds and location
        label114.setOpaque(false);

        //




        // frame
        setContentPane(panel);
        setSize(1520, 950);
        setTitle("Volvo Store");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        validate();

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == btnCheckout) {

            } else if (e.getSource() == btnClear) {

                txt1.setText("0.0");
                txt2.setText("0.0");
                txt3.setText("0.0");
                txt4.setText("0.0");
                txt5.setText("0.0");
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                txt7.setText("0.0");
                chk7.setSelected(false);
                chk6.setSelected(false);
                chk5.setSelected(false);
                chk4.setSelected(false);
                chk3.setSelected(false);
                chk2.setSelected(false);
                chk1.setSelected(false);
                chk.setSelected(false);

            } else if (e.getSource() == btnAbout) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Made by Evgeny Shumilov - 2014", "About",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            } else if (e.getSource() == btnExit) {

            }

        }
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double c = 0;
        double d = 0;
        double d1 = 0;
        double f = 0;
        double g = 0;
        double h = 0;

        double a1 = 0;
        double a2 = 0;
        double a3 = 0;
        double a4 = 0;
        double b1 = 0;
        double b2 = 0;
        double b3 = 0;
        double c1 = 0;
        double c2 = 0;
        double c3 = 0;


//radiobutton 
        if (e.getSource() == rb1) {

            txt1.setText("50800.0");
            txt2.setText("50800.0");

            panel.add(txt1);
            panel.add(txt2);

            m = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
            txt1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        }

        else if (rb2.isSelected()) {

            txt1.setText("42100.0");
            txt2.setText("42100.0");

            panel.add(txt1);
            panel.add(txt2);
            m = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
            txt1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        } else if (rb3.isSelected()) {

            txt1.setText("40950.0");
            txt2.setText("40950.0");

            panel.add(txt1);
            panel.add(txt2);
            m = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
            txt1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        } else if (rb4.isSelected()) {

            txt1.setText("49000.0");
            txt2.setText("49000.0");

            panel.add(txt1);
            panel.add(txt2);
            m = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
            txt1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        }

        if (chk.isSelected()) {

            a = 1350;

        }
        if (chk1.isSelected()) {

            b = 1500;

        }
        if (chk2.isSelected()) {

            c = 2600;

        }
        if (chk3.isSelected()) {

            d = 1250;

        }
        if (chk4.isSelected()) {

            d1 = 800;

        }
        if (chk5.isSelected()) {

            f = 1000;

        }
        if (chk6.isSelected()) {

            g = 600;

        }
        if (chk7.isSelected()) {

            h = 2400;

        }


        //p
        if (e.getSource() == cboProvinces) {

            String one = (String) cboProvinces.getSelectedItem();

            if (one.equals("Select Province")) {
                txt5.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt5);


            } else if (one.equals("Ontario")) {
                txt5.setText("1934.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Quebeck")) {
                txt5.setText("2200.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Nova Scotia")) {
                txt5.setText("1800.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("New Brunswick")) {
                txt5.setText("1999.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Manitoba")) {
                txt5.setText("2100.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("British Colombia")) {
                txt5.setText("1300.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Prince Edward Island")) {
                txt5.setText("2335.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Saskatchewan")) {
                txt5.setText("2120.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Alberta")) {
                txt5.setText("1670.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            } else if (one.equals("Newfoundland and Labrador")) {
                txt5.setText("3200.0");
                panel.add(txt5);
                k = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
            }

        }
        //color

        if (e.getSource() == cboAColor) {

            String one = (String) cboAColor.getSelectedItem();

            if (one.equals("Passion Red")) {
                a1 = 200;
                txt6.setText("200.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (one.equals("Black Sapphire")) {
                a2 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (one.equals("Crystal White Pearl")) {
                a3 = 200.0;
                txt6.setText("200.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (one.equals("Electric Silver")) {
                a4 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            }

        }
//leather
        if (e.getSource() == cboBColor) {

            String two = (String) cboBColor.getSelectedItem();

            if (two.equals("Black/Black ARTICO Leather")) {
                b1 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (two.equals("Alpaca Grey/Alpaca Grey ARTICO Leather")) {
                b2 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (two.equals("Almond Beige/Cashmere Beige ARTICO Leather")) {
                b3 = 350;
                txt6.setText("350.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            }
        }
//panel
        if (e.getSource() == cboCColor) {

            String one1 = (String) cboCColor.getSelectedItem();

            if (one1.equals("Aluminum")) {
                c1 = 300;
                txt6.setText("300.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (one1.equals("Burl Walnut Wood")) {
                c2 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            } else if (one1.equals("Dark Ash Wood")) {
                c3 = 0;
                txt6.setText("0.0");
                panel.add(txt6);

            }

        }
        //Double b1ll = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText());
        Double total = m + a + b + c + d + d1 + f + g + h + a1 + a2 + a3 +a4 + b1 + b2 + b3+ c1 + c2 +c3;


        Double total1 = a + b + c + d + d1 + f + g + h;


        Double totala = a1 + a2 + a3 +a4 + b1 + b2 + b3+ c1 + c2 +c3;


        Double FinalC= total + k;// - b1ll ;


        String total2 = Double.toString(total);
        String total21 = Double.toString(total1);
        String totalm = Double.toString(totala);
        String Final = Double.toString(FinalC);


        txt1.setText(total2);
        txt3.setText(total21);
        txt6.setText(totalm);
        txt4.setText(Final);

        validate();

    }

}
```

Comment: I saw `panel.setLayout(null);` and stopped.  Make the effort to understand and make use of appropriate layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.  If I were your tutor, I'd fail anybody who presented me with a solution using a `null` layout - but I'm old and cynical...

Answer (score 4):

This....

[image]

Is why you should use appropriate layout managers...

As to your problems...

You keep getting a `NullPointerException` because (as far as I've been able to test it), `m` and `k` are `null`...

You're using a single instance of an `ItemListener` listener for all your controls (that accept them), this is a really bad idea as it makes it difficult to determine 1- the current state and 2- what caused the event...

Personally, I prefer to use separate listeners where I can, so I can isolate exactly what is going on...

If you change `m` and `k` to be `double` instead of `Double`, this will solve the immediate issue

The next issue you will have is with the comparison of the values from the combo box...

In you event handler, you are using `if (one.equals("Passion Red")) {` to check the color option, but the actual entry is `Passion Red [add $200.00]`, meaning that it will never match...

I presume you have a number of these types of issues, so you're going to have to dig through your code to find them all...